# I want to inntegrate Chatbot of IBM with my electron and nodejs

Tags: node.js, electron, chatbot

I am have developed and application but not getting code based on IBM Watson for nodejs and html and how to integrate them!

Let me know if any guide?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the node package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-watson. Since electron runs on Node.js, you can just add all the npm packages you want as you would with a standard Node.js application.

Comment: Is there any sample git code available for js and html based chatbot using watson

Comment: Yes, in the link I provided...This is the README of the official Node.js SDK for IBM Watson. There are code samples provided for every part of the functionality that Watson offers. It has links to the documentation and their git repository.